# is g++ buggy ? and clang++ too ? g++ compiled code with -O0 and -O1 options behaves differently the same is true for clang++ with -O0 and -O2

Tags: c++, g++

The code bellow named as file "main000.cpp" is compiled and executed on a linux machine with the subsequent command line:

```
g++  -std=c++11 -m32 -O0  main000.cpp ; ./a.out
```

and gets executed normally

while if compiled and executed changing O0 to O1

```
g++  -std=c++11 -m32 -O1  main000.cpp ; ./a.out
```

doesn't work and generates a stack dump

any body that knows why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int Token;

const Token tokenBase=0x80000000;

enum        classId{
    classNoId=tokenBase,
    classPrimitiveId,
};

struct classInfo{classId id;wstring name;};

classInfo classInfos[]={ 
    {classNoId,L"classNoID"},
    {classPrimitiveId,L"classPrimitiveId"},
};

int main(){
    int id=classInfos[0].id;
    return 0*id;
}
```

Comment: This is usually a sign of latent bugs in your code. Try debugging, stress testing, valgrind, etc.

Comment: Do you see any bug in those 20 lines of code ?

Comment: What happens with -O2 and -O3? What does that stack trace say?

Comment: you have an undefined behaviour, compile this code with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and try to spot it.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis The compiler **optimizes out** s.th. you've been misleadingly relying on in your code! UB most likely ...

Comment: -O2 or -O3 give the same result

Comment: The code is there. It is 20 lines. Where is the error ?

Comment: As mentioned above, compile this with warning flags.

Comment: Compiled with warning flags, I corrected the non initialization of the function adding NULL but it doesn't change anything. All flags where enabled and don't give anything.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Let's _unfold it_ ...

Comment: Note that `0 * n` always results in `0`...

Comment: Obviously, I just used it to avoid the compiler to tell me that I didn't used somewhere the variable "id".

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Was that your last edit? Please point out that you have solved that in your post. Otherwise it will be pretty confusing for anyone else reading this!

Comment: You could try to enable the optimizations that -O1 does one by one and see which one crashes the app.

Comment: The compiler's smart enough to notice that zero times a number is always zero --- that won't necessarily help. To truly force the compiler not to optimise out a value, you have to write it to a volatile variable.

Comment: The use of that unsigned int value for your first enum value is potentially problematic.

Comment: "Generates a stack dump"? What does it print?

Comment: You may have a broken standard library installation. Use a debugger to see where the crash is.

Comment: Is that really your *exact* code? I get `error: ‘uint’ does not name a type`. If it doesn't compile, it can't crash.

Comment: It compiles and runs fine here (after I changed uint to unsigned int).  I'm on OS/X mavericks, with the latest Xcode, compiling with clang++ (Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn))

Comment: _'is g++ buggy ? and clang++ too ?'_ Very unlikely ...

Comment: Works for me too (both clang and gcc). And when I hand-read the code I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: @KeithThompson it does compile on Linux as is (only with `-std=c++11`). This is probably a libstdc++ bug.

Comment: I enabled optimizations one by one of O1 as found somewhere and none of them recreates the error.

Comment: The current code is the minimal one and compiles. I changed it some times so it may be that a previous version had some error.

Comment: The stack dump gives: *** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0952e044 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x767c2)[0xf75117c2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77510)[0xf7512510]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xf76b5a3f]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE4_Rep10_M_destroyERKS1_+0x1b)[0xf771db2b]
./a.out[0x8048793]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x33791)[0xf74ce791]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3381d)[0xf74ce81d]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0xf74b490d]
./a.out

Comment: @n.m.: Ack! Yes, it does compile without error with `-std=c++11`, but not without it. `gcc -std=c++11 -E` shows a declaration `typedef unsigned int uint;` in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h`. There is no declaration of `uint` mentioned in the C++ standard. George: Just to avoid confusion, you might replace `uint` by `unsigned int`; the fact that g++ accepts `uint` is probably a bug.

Comment: I forgot to correct uint to unsigned int, but it compiled anyway. I corrected the code. So we found a second bug: uint is interpreted as unsinged int !

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis I think that you might be running the wrong program. There's no `free` anywhere in your code, so there shouldn't be any memory errors resulting from a bad `free`.

Comment: @templatetypedef Maybe there's a problem with the standard library? The stack trace seems to be generated by the string's destructor (char traits ... destroy) no?

Comment: I Executed                                                             rm ./a.out; g++  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11 -m32 -O0  main000.cpp;./a.out

Comment: This is almost a repost of [his other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355369/using-c-g-and-compiling-with-out-optimizations-every-thing-is-ok-when-i-u).

Comment: Have you made sure your compilers and libraries are up to date? What version of g++ are you using?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Are you on a 64 bit machine? Do you have the 32 bit libraries installed? When you run the program, are the correct 32 bit libraries found? I am asking these because of the `-m32` flag you are using. I can't reproduce this on my machine; without the `-m32` everything is fine on my 64 bit machine. I don't have the 32 bit libraries, so I can't test with the `-m32` flag.

Comment: Yes I am on a 64 bit machine. I will check it now without -m32. I have the 32 bit libraries installed. I checked and taking out -m32 I have the same error.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report for the spurious `uint` declaration: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59945

Comment: Is `0x80000000` a valid literal? Is it of type `int` or `uint`?

Comment: In order to alleviate you from 0x80000000 change it to 55 . Generically speaking 0x80000000 is an unsigned number because signed numbers end at 0x7FFFFFFF. The signed number -0x80000000 is what we mean by 0x80000000 .

Comment: You most certainly have something broken about your system. Try reinstalling everything you can, starting with g++.

Comment: Did you compiled it with -O0 and -O1 options and it runs in both cases ?

Comment: @George Are you going to consider closing/deleting the other question since this one supersedes it?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: Oh, so if the same problem happens with `55` then I guess that's not the issue. Are the identifiers conflicting with an external library by any chance? What happens if you change them to something less common?

Comment: The other question was different but I changed it to that one. I will have to delete it and repost a new one when the current problem is solved, because it seems that there are various problems.

Comment: By the way, this runs fine on both Clang 3.2 and GCC 4.8.1 on my computer with both `-O1` and `-O2`, but I'm on Windows, not Linux.

Comment: Actually, this runs fine on Clang 3.3 and GCC 4.7.3 on Linux as well.

Comment: Works on OSX with with clang 3.3 without errors. `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11 -m32 -O1 ./test.cpp` - I second that it's probably an issue with your installation.

Comment: @Mehrdad: `0x80000000`'s type is the first of `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int` in which its value can be represented. On most systems, it will be of type `unsigned int` if `unsigned int` is 32 bits or wider. (Decimal integer literals, on the other hand, are always of some signed type.)

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: You're making assumptions about the width of `int` and `unsigned int`. The standard guarantees only that they're at least 32 bits. See my previous comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Oh interesting, so there's no way to represent `INT_MIN` hexadecimally as `int` without a cast?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I believe that's correct -- which is why `<limits.h>` implementations typically do things like `#define INT_MIN (-INT_MAX - 1)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: "The standard guarantees only that [int and unsigned int are] at least 32 bits." Shouldn't that be 16 bits?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Yes, you're right of course. The C standard only guarantees that `int` and `unsigned int` are at least 16 bits wide. (POSIX requires them to be at least 32 bits.)

Answer (score 5):

For both `-O1` and `-O2`, this runs fine for me on

- Clang 3.2 and GCC 4.8.1 (Windows)
- Clang 3.3 and GCC 4.7.3 (Linux)

so it's probably a problem with your setup. I'd suggest running it inside `gdb` and getting a `backtrace`.

And make sure you're not linking libraries with conflicting identifiers defined.